# How to check two values are equal in ember handlebar without checking its type?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

{{eq '1' 1}} -> matches type and returns false

Link:https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-truth-helpers

eq  if (a === b)    {{if (eq a b)}}

In documentation it is checking for type tooo

I have also tried using is-equal helper it too returns false....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s rare that people want that kind of comparison, so you probably won’t find an addon that does it. But you could use a modified version of [Ember Truth Helpers’s `eq`](https://github.com/jmurphyau/ember-truth-helpers/blob/b2e3a728f4cd5b2f24cd9a5c20e99e80e72cc914/addon/helpers/equal.js) to use `==` instead of `===`:

```
import { helper } from '@ember/component/helper';

export function equal(params) {
  return params[0] == params[1];
}

export default helper(equal);
```

If you place such a file at `app/helpers/double-eq` you could use it with `(double-eq 1 '1')`. Probably there’s a clearer name than that, but you get the idea.